# Delamination in resin prints

Tags: resin, delamination

I have observed some occasional delamination in horizontal layers of my resin prints — see two examples:

[image: downward]
[image: upward]

What is the cause, and how can this be minimized?

Comment: can you also post more information about your setup: The printer model, resin type, and exposure settings would be helpful to know. Also I'm having a hard time seeing what is going on in these images, they are a little too zoomed in.

Comment: A too low room temperature can cause this too

Answer (score 2):

With the information provided my thought is that your layers are underexposed for their thickness. Each layer is just barely bonding to the layer above it. After being pulled on by layers below eventually one of the layers fails. This is especially likely to happen on a thin part of the print any may need more support if it is followed by wider layers. But I would suggest trying to increase your exposure time first.

option two: it could be your FEP if that has seen too much use it may be time to replace it.

[calibrating a resin 3D printer](https://ameralabs.com/blog/key-things-calibrating-resin-3d-printer/)

Comment: true, but I suspect it's more a model-alignment error. SLA hates flat overhangs, it much prefers them tilted, best by 45°

Answer (score 1):

[Besides the options of underexposure or bad FEP film](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/a/14947/8884), there's also the option of the print being in a bad orientation for printing. Often, the quality gets better if you tilt the model some degrees. You do have to clean up some places, but the stresses from pulling free of the FEP get distributed more evenly and are lower, resulting in generally better prints.

Other factors that can impact the print quality is the resin's viscosity: the more viscous, the more likely resin can't flow in enough. Resin's viscosity is antiproportional to the room temperature - the hotter the room, the less viscous the resin.

Comment: What is the ideal temperature range for printing with resin?

Comment: @0xF2 operational ranges for resins are generally 10 °C or 15 °C to 40 °C. The best temperature will be in your MSDS